# WordPress child nav a:current styling

Tags: php, css, wordpress, nav

I'm currently working on a site for a client - It is all working fine but within the navigation I have setup of for the child links using the following code

```
<div id="sub_nav_del">
                    <h4>Take a seat</h4>
                    <?php
                    $subnav_parent = ($post->post_parent) ? $post->post_parent : $post->ID;
                    $pages = get_pages('child_of=' . $subnav_parent . '&sort_column=menu_order');
                    $count = 0;
                    foreach($pages as $page)
                    { ?>



                    <ul>
                        <li>
                        <h5 class="del">
                            <a href="<?php echo get_page_link($page->ID)  ?>" ><?php echo  $page->post_title ?></a>
                        </h5>
                        </li>
                        </ul>
                    <?php
                    }   
                    ?>
                </div>
```

You can see an example at http://www.lagourmetteria.co.uk/take-a-seat/wine-room/, for that page I would like the current pages link orange.

I would like it to make the current link to be a different colour just within the child navigation. Is there a simple way to do this, unfortunately my PHP skills aren't fantastic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have what you need as a class in the `<body>` which is `wine-room` (probably the slug). So in your CSS you can do the following magic:

```
body.wine-room a[href*="wine-room"],
body.tasting-room a[href*="tasting-room"],
body.food-drink-menu a[href*="food-drink-menu"],
body.have-it-all-private-parties a[href*="have-it-all-private-parties"]
{
    color: orange !important;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Added all slugs on that submenu.

**UPDATE 2**

Added `!important` to supersede any other style.

Comment: Hey Henrik, thanks for the quick reply unfortunately by adding that to my css is having no effect. I've never used the a[href in css before, so I'm kinda un sure where to go.

Comment: Thank you so much, works a treat. Just for future reference did you get the slug from this line? <body class="page page-id-61 page-child parent-pageid-33 page-template page-template-take_a_seat-php logged-in admin-bar tasting-room">

Comment: Yes. Wordpress usually adds the slug as default to the `<body>` as a class which is really handy in situations like these that need specific looks on specific pages.

Comment: Hey I had it all working, but I've added some extra pages and its seem to have broke. http://www.lagourmetteria.co.uk/

Comment: Create a new question linking to this one. I'm currently to busy to help you this time. But with reference to this it should be easy for someone else to fix. Good luck and best regards, Henrik.