# Adding 'active' class current menu item w/ JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There have been several SO solutions to this, but I haven't had any luck getting them to work.  JQuery beginner trying to work through a solution to add an 'active' class to the active list item in a simple navigation menu:

```
   <div id="main-menu">

      <ul>
         <li><a href="/site/about">About Us</a></li>
         <li><a href="/site/work">Our Work</a></li>
         <li><a href="/site/contact">Contact Us</a></li>    
      </ul>

    </div>
```

A previous SO post indicated that this worked, but I've had no success so far.  I'm using pretty permalinks in wordpress, so the full path to any page is like:

http://www.foobar.com/site/about/

This is my work so far:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    var url = window.location.pathname,
        urlRegExp = new RegExp(url.replace(/\/$/,''));    
        $('#main-menu li').each(function(){
            if(urlRegExp.test(this.href)){
                $(this).addClass('active');
            }
        });
});​
</script>
```

I've tried several solutions, including changing how I write the href, etc.  The part of the code I'm really foggy on is the urlRegExp part...Any help?

Comment: you are trying to find a `href` in a `<li>`.

Comment: Why not use what Wordpress has to offer in the classes it sets on the `<body>` like a previous answer I've made on SO, http://stackoverflow.com/a/12272075/600101? No JS, only WP and CSS in symbios. Saves the world some trees. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try with

```
    $('#main-menu li a').each(function(){
        if(urlRegExp.test(this.href)){

        ...
    });
```

instead of

```
    $('#main-menu li').each(function(){
        if(urlRegExp.test(this.href)){
        ...
    });
```

since `href` attribute you're looking on next line with `this.href` is applied on links, and not on list-items

then, if you need to apply the class `active` on `<li>` element just use

```
 $(this).parent().addClass('active'); 
 // or  $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
 // or pure-JS : this.parentNode.className += 'active';
```

Comment: So maybe add the class to the `parent()`?

Comment: "$(this).attr('href')" better than "this.href", isn't it ?

Comment: No, is less efficient since you are 1) calling the `jQuery` function 2) calling the method `attr()`

Comment: I see, thanks... means that this.href is a use of JS only and no JQuery... To much use of JQuery kill JS efficiency sometime... :o)

Comment: I agree you might as well use `this.href`, but it really won't be that much of a performance killer to use jQuery to get it. Some people like to use jQuery for everything possible when they're already using it for a lot of the code, so it's up to them. Also, I think href is safe enough, but jQuery would take care of cross browser problems when attempting `node.href`, in the case where using `.`something isn't supported, or any weird problems.

Comment: Thanks @FabrizioCalderan I'll try it out now and will let you know!  I appreciate the speedy help.

Comment: this still isn't working for some reason....  Could it have to do with the way I'm writing the href?  Should I write out the full path, or is '/site/about enough' (for example)?

Comment: urlRegExp is stripping all slashes from the pathname. If your href attribute contain slashes the test will always fail.

Comment: okay, I understand that. How do you recommend I write out my pathname in the href attribute?

Comment: assuming my href are in the form of `path/subpath` I would only write `if(url.test(this.href)){ ...`

Comment: @TheNally if you don't solved yet let pass in javascript chat :)

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan sorry for being so slow with this.  Could you take a look at my work?  The JQuery is at the end of the source code.  I've subbed in your last bit of code, but no sign of the 'active' class. [link](http://www.eggprocessinginnovations.com/site/about)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16886/discussion-between-thenally-and-fabrizio-calderan)

Answer (score 2):

this.href is wrong (should be $(this), plus you're checking on the list element, rather than li. Try this:

```
$('#main-menu li > a').each(function(){
        if(urlRegExp.test($(this).attr('href'))){
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });
```

Comment: this.href is not wrong: it will work fine and it's more efficient than passing through $() function