# Converting CSS template to asp.net with masterpages

Tags: javascript, html, css

I bought an css template.
which implements navigation such that.

```
 <li class="current"><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
 <li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
 <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
 <li><a href="elements.html">Elements</a></li>
 <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
```

It contains navigation  tag in every html file and mark the list item class as current for the current page.

Now i am converting this into master page layout.
How can i detect current page and add class to the list item with JavaScript.
Or any other solution to this problem.

Comment: show your asp.net code atleast

Comment: In .net i have markup only no .net stuff... I am not using mvc its webforms only

Comment: If you saw an example in PHP, could you rewrite it as .net?

Comment: Please see this solution is very similar to what you want to achieve. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497289/adding-active-class-current-menu-item-w-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one simple way to do this (using jQuery):

```
function syncMenu () {
        var url = window.location.href, pageStart, pageEnd, pageName;
        pageStart = url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1;
        pageEnd = url.lastIndexOf(".");
        pageName = url.substring(pageStart, pageEnd);

        $('#Menu').find('li').removeClass('selected');
        $('#Menu').find('a[href^="' + pageName + '"]').parent().addClass('current');

}
```

Call this function as the first thing when your page loads i.e. first thing in `document.ready`.

The idea is that you have the name of the page as the `anchor` `href`. We retrieve the page name from the current url and use that to search the `a` in all `li`s which contains that page name as its `href`. Add a class (current in your case) to that `li`.

Comment: One more question i also have a element which show's home >> current page.. hard coded in every page how can i sent e current page with code

Comment: That depends. If your element is separate for the current page, then simply do a `$('#elemId').text(pageName)`.