# 'active' class not adding to all list items

Tags: jquery, css

I'm building a very simple menu using an unordered list. I'd like the current page to be highlighted when it's selected.

My problem is that one of the menu items is getting the `active` class added when it's clicked, but none of the others are when I change the page from the menu, which is why this is so confusing to me. There are no errors in the console when I check. I even tried regex method from **[this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497289/adding-active-class-current-menu-item-w-jquery)** but it still isn't working for me with all menu items.

HTML

```
<div class="page-menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="list-item"><a href="#Item1">Item 1</a></li>
    <li class="list-item"><a href="#Item2">Item 2</a></li>
    <li class="list-item"><a href="#Item3">Item 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.active {
  background-color:red;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.page-menu a').each(function(index) {
        if(this.href.trim() == window.location)
            $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});
```

Any ideas on why `active` would be added to one list item but not the others?

Comment: Because the `href` only matches for one of them? And your adding class `selected`, not `active`

Comment: @tymeJV the class at the bottom was a typo...it's updated now. I thought the `if` was checking the current URL...is that not correct?

Comment: It is, but why would you expect more than 1 active class to be added?

Comment: The jQuery loops through all your item elements and checks if the `href` of it matches the currently location. There can only be one location at the time so there is only 1 match. This match is made active.

Comment: Note: Your sample links are #hash bookmarks. Window.location will return *the full URL*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there may be some confusion in your question. Based on your question and comments, there you're wanting to select the current location. Therefore there should only be ***one*** location selected at any given time as the browser window can only navigate to one place at time.

In addition, you're validating the `href` attribute which contains a hash (`#Item1`) against a `window.location.href` which returns a full URL (i.e. `http://www.example.com/something.html#Item1`). In this scenario, you're `href` value will never match.

Instead try matching against the value returned by `window.location.hash` like so:

```
$(function() {
    $('.page-menu a[href="' + window.location.hash + '"]').addClass("active");
});
```

You can eliminate the loop altogether by identifying the one location through the use of [jQuery attribute selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/).

```js
// Test snippet to add hash to current URL.
window.location.hash = "Item1";

$(function() {
    $('.page-menu a[href="' + window.location.hash + '"]').addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="list-item"><a href="#Item1">Item 1</a></li>
    <li class="list-item"><a href="#Item2">Item 2</a></li>
    <li class="list-item"><a href="#Item3">Item 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/warlock5658/wmduj4b9/)**