# Coloring a <a> when inside a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

i created a sub category sorting menu in my woo commerce shop pages.
i want to make the  that links to the page i'm inside right now to be colored in red. 
i don't have a problem with the css just with the js script.
how can i make it highlight the current  ?
this is the sorting menu i created:
[image]
lets say this is the ul im using:

```
<ul class="wooc_sclist" id="catmenu">
<li class="category " ><h2><a href="..." class="...">Bla</a></h2></li>
</ul>
```

this is how i create my sorting menu:

```
function tutsplus_product_subcategories( $cat) {
$parentid = $cat->term_id; 
$args = array(
    'parent' => $parentid
);
$terms = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );

if ( $terms || is_subcategory() ) {

    echo '<ul class="wooc_sclist" id="catmenu">';

        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

            echo '<li class="category " >';                 

                echo '<h2>';
                    echo '<a href="' .  esc_url( get_term_link( $term ) ) . '" class="' . $term->slug .'">';
                        echo $term->name;
                    echo '</a>';
                echo '</h2>';

            echo '</li>';


        }

        echo '</ul>';
    }
}
```

Comment: You need current menu highlight  as like current page menu name like highlight . I am right ?

Comment: @MDMostofa Yes you are

Answer (score 0):

In wordpress you will have class current_page_item when you seleted menu.
You can set color of `<a>` at here

```
.current_page_item a{color: #xxxxxx;}
```

And if you want to set color when hover

```
.category a:hover{color: #xxxxxx;}
```

Comment: that's great that the class exist but i need to add it only to the current page somehow

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery like this is header.php or footer.php file

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.current_page_item').css('color','red');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: this menu is not something wordpress built, i did so it is not adding this class automatic to my sorting menu

Comment: will you provide me url so i can fix the issue

Comment: url to my website? its localhost

Answer (score 0):

Using [jQuery hover](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) you can toggle the color of your anchors.

With [jQuery on click](http://api.jquery.com/on/) you may handle the click event.
Inside the click handler you can use e.preventDefault(); to avoid to jump to another page.

With $(this).index() you may test if the element is the first one in the list.

With $(this).find('a').toggleClass('active'); you may toggle the class active for the anchor element.

In order to test if an anchor is active (has the class active) you may use:

```
var isActive = $('#catmenu li').find('a.active').length > 0 ? true : false;
```

I added a button to do this test.

```js
$(function () {
  $('#catmenu li').hover(function(e) {
    $(this).find('a').css('color', 'red');
  }, function(e) {
    $(this).find('a').css('color', '');
  });
  
  
  $('#catmenu li').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if ($(this).index() == 0) { // if first category
      $(this).find('a').toggleClass('active');
    }
  });

  $('#btn').on('click', function(e) {
    var isActive = $('#catmenu li').find('a.active').length > 0 ? true : false;
    console.log('First category is active: ' + isActive);
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: #acaf2c;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>


<ul class="wooc_sclist" id="catmenu">
    <li class="category " ><h2><a href="..." class="...">Bla</a></h2></li>
    <li class="category " ><h2><a href="..." class="...">Bla</a></h2></li>
    <li class="category " ><h2><a href="..." class="...">Bla</a></h2></li>
</ul>
<button id="btn">Check if first category is active</button>
```

Comment: Im not looking for hover,but when i'm in the first li <a> link that the text will be bold or something

Comment: @ssabin What do you mean for "hen i'm in the first li <a> "? How and when does it happen?

Comment: When you click on the first category in the menu,i want that it will be bold. i want the page to recognize that i am in the link that the li <a> has and bold it

Comment: @ssabin Answer updated. I hope it could help you. Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this JavaScripts code :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('ul li a').click(function(){
    $('li a').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
});
```

take a look my demo link 
[Demo link](https://codepen.io/mostofa/full/GqyZgQ/)

Comment: #ssabin You checked my demo link.
You want it i am right ?

Comment: YOU get help from this link ..     https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/add-active-navigation-class-based-on-url/

same thing and you get answer heer ..    
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497289/adding-active-class-current-menu-item-w-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Check this code is working here :
I hope solve it.

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul li a').click(function(){
   $('li a').removeClass("active");
   $(this).addClass("active");
  });
  });
```

```css
body 
{
margin: 0; 
padding: 0; 
font-size: 100%; 
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.menu ul{}
.menu ul li {}
.navbar-inverse.menu ul li a {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
 background:transparent;
}
.navbar-inverse.menu ul li a:hover, .navbar-inverse.menu ul li a.active, .navbar-inverse.menu ul li a.active:hover {

 background: rgba(183, 51, 106, 0.38);
}
.navbar-inverse {
    border-radius: 0;
}
ul.wooc_sclist li a {
  color: green;
}
ul.wooc_sclist li a:hover, ul li a.active, ul li a.active:hover {
  color:red;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="wooc_sclist" id="catmenu">
<li class="category " ><h2><a href="#" class="">Bla 1</a></h2></li>
  <li class="category " ><h2><a href="#" class="">Bla 2</a></h2></li>
  <li class="category " ><h2><a href="#" class="">Bla 3</a></h2></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I am not familiar with jQuery jet but here is how you can do it with pure JavaScript. If you understand the concept it's gonna be easy to do it in jQuery if you wish.

```
//get list item from navmenu
var navUl = document.getElementById("catmenu").childNodes;
var address = document.URL;

//base function for returning arr of LIs 
function mapForEachLi(object) {
    var arr = [];
    for (index in object) {
        if (object[index].nodeType == 1) { //put only element nodes in array
            arr.push(object[index]);
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
//get array of nav LIs
var navLis = mapForEachLi(navUl);

//loop trough array of LIs
for (var i = 0; i < navLis.length; i++) {
    //get value a tag href attribute
    var liLink = navLis[i].firstChild.getAttribute("href");
    //campare current page URL with a tag href value 
    //if they are the same then change style
    if (document.baseURI === liLink) {
        navLis[i].style.textDecoration = 'underline';//you can change CSS class if you want
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

[Click for live demo](http://clients.leexor.com/menu/)

If you want to use  Jquery and javascripts code :

```
$(function() {
     var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href
.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
     $("nav ul a").each(function(){
          if($(this).attr("href") == pgurl || $(this).attr("href") == '' )
          $(this).addClass("active");
     })
});
```

Or if u want to use plain javascript code :

```
function setActive() {
  aObj = document.getElementById('nav').getElementsByTagName('a');
  for(i=0;i<aObj.length;i++) { 
    if(document.location.href.indexOf(aObj[i].href)>=0) {
      aObj[i].className='active';
    }
  }
}

window.onload = setActive;
```

Here you get your src files:

[Click here for Source files from github --](https://github.com/MDMOSTOFA/active-class-on-current-page.git)

[Click here for source link](https://webdesignerhut.com/activeclass-navigation-menu/)